# How to copy database file in Application Support directory in Cocoa without losing data?

Tags: objective-c, macos, sqlite, cocoa, osx-yosemite

I have tried this code but it creates `BLANK` `database.sqlite` file in document directory.

```
- (void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded
{
    // First, test for existence.
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"prediction.sqlite"];



    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];

    if (success) return;
    // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"prediction.sqlite"];

    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];


    if (!success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);

    }
}
```

How do I ensure that when I copy database file it does not create an empty database?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That code never attempts to create a database file.

Comment: but m just copy database file from NSbundle to document directory.

Comment: No you're not doing that at all.

Comment: why? but i want anyhow  to copy file.

Comment: OK so which statement is copying the file?

Comment: @trojanfoe please check my updated question and let me know the solution.

Comment: is this plain sqlite, or core data? is the database journaled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First your code were not attempts to create a database file.

So... You just want to copy the database file “prediction.sqlite” from source bundle to UserDomain dir?
 If this is your purpose，You should pay attention to the code:

```
  if (success) return;
// The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
```

The correct should be：

```
      if (!success) return;
// The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
```

The directories returned by `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` are not guaranteed to exist; you need to create them yourself, if necessary (see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-SW5)). NSFileManager's `createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:` can help with that.@Anomie

try those code:(before you copy the "prediction.sqlite" file, you need add the file in to your project bundle.):
[image]

```
- (void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded
{
    // First, test for existence.
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"prediction.sqlite"];

    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];

    if (!success){
        // create the directories, because the directories returned by NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains are not guaranteed to exist
        if (![fileManager createFileAtPath:writableDBPath contents:nil attributes:nil]) {
            return;
        }
    }

    // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"prediction.sqlite"];

    // remove the same file, before you copy the file
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:writableDBPath error:nil];

    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];

    if (!success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);

    }
}
```

Comment: After implementing above method problem not solved   and it copies blank database file without tables.

Comment: Why I can copy the database with tables.......I have updated the answer，and see if it can help you

Comment: @Stoull this code copies a database structure, but not the data.